# How can I tell if a site uses dofollow or nofollow links?

Tags: nofollow, dofollow

I would like to solicit links from a small business marketing site.  I think it uses nofollow, but its robots tag is `<meta name="Robots" content="All" />`.

How do I tell if it is a dofollow site or nofollow site?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `dofollow`, if you can't find either `nofollow` on the page or site then it is assumed that all links are follow.

You can tell if a site is no follow by viewing the source code and searching for `nofollow`, if you can't find it within `content="nofollow"` or `rel="nofollow"` then all links on that page are follow. You can simplify the process by using a browser addon, I coded a simple FireFox plugin several years ago  that allows users to simply [hover over a link and find out if it uses nofollow](https://github.com/SimonHayter/Hover-Nofollow), I have no idea if it still works but in theory it should because the code is very simple.

If your looking to automate the process and harvest these details in bulk then you will need to visit a black hat forum or something, its not something that any normal application or browser will do for you.

Comment: A page might also link to a redirect script that is blocked by `robots.txt`. This is also effectively "nofollow" without explicitly including `rel="nofollow"` (or `content="nofollow"`) in the page source.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right Click to on your browser and click “View page source”or use short cut key <kbd>ctrl + U</kbd>
2. Next, Search the nofollow.
3. If you see a `rel=”nofollow”` attribute, in that link than its nofollow. Otherwise, the link is dofollow.